# laravel 5.3 collective/html not working

Tags: laravel

install composer require laravelcollective/html and get this error :

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
>   php artisan optimize
>   Generating optimized class loader
>   The compiled class file has been removed.

how can resolve this ???
Tanks.

Comment: I think it is normal your packange should work now

Comment: @msonowal But it does not work.
When I typed out the form and press the TAB key nothing will happen

Comment: what press the TAB key could you explain?

Comment: for write the automatically cods of open form in laravel
 for ex: when press TAB show this cods: 

{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST','action'=>'AdminUsersController@store']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name','Name:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div> 

to end .....